# How to take log of only affected rows during update_batch in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I searched the net but didn't find any solution to my problem.
I have a form which is generated dynamically i get each fields in array and insert_batch it
to database and also the same way i update_batch it,

now I want to take log of my database during update_batch,
my data comes in array is there any way to take log of only affected rows?

Here is my simple code which i send to model for update_batch

```
            $name            = $this->input->post('name');
                $type            = $this->input->post('type');
                $model           = $this->input->post('model');
                $license         = $this->input->post('license');
                $machine_no      = $this->input->post('machine_no');
                $value           = $this->input->post('value');
                $bought_date     = $this->input->post('bought_date');
                $bought_place    = $this->input->post('bought_place');
                $cur_price       = $this->input->post('cur_price');
                $bought_seller   = $this->input->post('bought_seller');
                $sfunds          = $this->input->post('sfunds');
                $u_rec_id        = $this->session->userdata('rec_id');
                $serial          = $this->session->userdata('serial');

                $all_array = array();
                $form_data = array();
                if($name)
                {
                    if(is_array($name))
                    {

                        for($j=0; $j<count($name); $j++)
                        {
                            $this->ci_form = array(
                                        'name'                    => $name[$j],
                                        'vehicle_type'            => $type[$j],
                                        'made_model'              => $model[$j],
                                        'license'                 => $license[$j],
                                        'machine_no'              => $machine_no[$j],
                                        'value'                   => $value[$j],
                                        'date_acquired'           => change_datei($bought_date[$j]),
                                        'place_acquired'          => $bought_place[$j],
                                        'current_value'           => $cur_price[$j],
                                        'seller'                  => $bought_seller[$j],
                                        'fund_source'             => $sfunds[$j],
                                        'userid'                  => $id,
                                        'u_rec_id'                => $u_rec_id,
                                        'serial'                  => $serial,
                                        'regdate'                 => date('Y-m-d H:m:s')

                              );
                              array_push($all_array, $this->ci_form);
                        }


                    }
               }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `log of database`? if you want to know how many rows are affected use `$this->db->affected_rows();`, if you want to get the sql query use `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: I have for example one table job_history and one table job_history_log, the fields in both table are same for security reason if any person changes any records in job_history i insert the updated records into job_history_log did you understand what i mean or not?

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you want to record `job_history` changes during the time. If I were you, I would just update `job_history` table and insert that row in `job_history_log` at the same time. `job_history_log` should has two additional fields: `log_id` as primary key and auto generated `timestamp` to save the insertion time.

Comment: Would you consider accepting this if I post it again as the answer?

Comment: My dear i now those things that is not what i want

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I confused by tens of opened tabs :|